# Implement the merge sort algorithm to sort a list of numbers in ascending order

Tags: python, data-structures, mergesort

I was trying to implement merge sort in python, here's what I got:

```
def merge_sort(num_list):
    if len(num_list) < 2:
        return num_list
    else:
        mid = len(num_list) // 2
        left_list = merge_sort(num_list[: mid])
        right_list = merge_sort(num_list[mid: ])
        merge(left_list,right_list)

def merge(left_list,right_list):
    sorted_list = []
    i = j = 0
    while (i < len(left_list) and j < len(right_list)):
        if left_list[i] <= right_list[j]:
            sorted_list.append(left_list[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            sorted_list.append(right_list[j])
            j += 1
    while(i < len(left_list)):
        sorted_list.append(left_list[i])
        i += 1
    while j < len(right_list):
        sorted_list.append(right_list[j])
        j += 1
    return sorted_list
```

And I received this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 34, in <module>
sorted_list = merge_sort(num_list)
line 9, in merge_sort
left_list=merge_sort(num_list[:mid])
line 12, in merge_sort
merge(left_list,right_list)
line 18, in merge
while i<len(left_list) and j<len(right_list):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Could somebody help me understand what went wrong in the code and how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning the merged list in your `merge_sort` method in your `else` condition. The following change will make your function work correctly (note the `return` at the end):

```
def merge_sort(num_list):
    if len(num_list) < 2:
        return num_list
    mid = len(num_list) // 2
    left_list = merge_sort(num_list[: mid])
    right_list = merge_sort(num_list[mid: ])
    return merge(left_list,right_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return the merged list at the end of your `merge_sort()` method. It should be:

```
def merge_sort(num_list):
    if len(num_list) < 2:
        return num_list
    else:
        mid = len(num_list) // 2
        left_list = merge_sort(num_list[: mid])
        right_list = merge_sort(num_list[mid: ])
        return merge(left_list,right_list)
```

Python returns `None` when functions exit without a return statement, so when it gets to here:

```
left_list = merge_sort(num_list[: mid])
right_list = merge_sort(num_list[mid: ])
```

if `merge_sort()` doesn't return anything, then it will assign `None` to those variables. Thus, when it gets to the while loop on line 18 in `merge()`, `left_list` and/or `right_list` are `None`, which gives you that `TypeError` when you try to take the length of them.